# Random exclamation mark in email body using CDO

Tags: asp-classic, cdo.message

We are getting random exclamation (!) mark in email body using CDO object in Classic ASP.

We are not getting this exclamation mark with outlook. Problem only occur with Lotus Notes client. We use IIS SMTP server to send email.

**Edit**

```
Set myMail= Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
myMail.Subject="Business and Company News on your Mobile Device"
myMail.From="no-reply@test.com"
myMail.To="some@email.com"
htmlbody = htmlbody (coming runtime)
myMail.BodyPart.ContentTransferEncoding = "quoted-printable"
myMail.HTMLBody = htmlbody
myMail.Send
```

I think client is not using SMTP. But they are using LotusNotes for sure.

Comment: Please explain a bit more: you are developing web pages in classic asp ? And you are sending mails using the IIS SMTP server ? Where is the Lotus Notes client coming in this picture. Please show some code what you are doing.

Comment: Set myMail= Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
 myMail.Subject="Business and Company News on your Mobile Device"
 myMail.From="no-reply@test.com"
 myMail.To="some@email.com"
 htmlbody = htmlbody (coming runtime)
 myMail.BodyPart.ContentTransferEncoding = "quoted-printable" 
 myMail.HTMLBody = htmlbody 
 myMail.Send

I think client is not using SMTP. But they are using LotusNotes for sure.

Answer (score 6):

Exclamation marks in emails are usually caused by lines being too long. Dump the email body you're creating in ASP to a file and examine it. Try to split lines at sensible places with newlines. I assume this is a HTML message - place newlines after appropriate HTML tags.

Comment: Can you expand on this, perhaps provide an example? I have the same problem but none of the answers above are working for me.

Comment: Hmmm well OK I posted this three years ago, based one something I vaguely remembered... but my vague memory was that lines that were longer than some limit produced ! marks. Of course, your ! marks might be produced for some other reason. Try dumping the raw body you are trying to send, and see if the ! marks correlate with something (odd unicode characters, lines of particular length, etc).

Answer (score 5):

Only difference I see with my code is

```
 .HTMLBody= psBody
 .HTMLBodyPart.ContentTransferEncoding = "quoted-printable"
```

So `HTMLBodyPart....` in stead of `BodyPart.....`

Don't know if that makes a difference, but you can try it.

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. We were word wrapping at 78 characters. When we sent email the exclamation marks started appearing. Since we are also putting text version of the body, looks like we have to specify the encoding. Same issue was not there when we tested using other components such as Chilkat or default .net MailMessage class.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, the "quoted-printable" solution works but it generates problems with binary attachments. So I wrote a little VbScript function that fixes long strings and makes the htmlbody compatible with all clients. Here it is:

```
<%
'
' **** fix CDOSYS exclamation mark problem - TFI 10/22/2013 - v1.1
'
' This function breaks a string into 76 chars (or less) lines, thus avoiding
' the "exclamation mark" problem when sending e-mails through CDOSYS component
' v.1.1 - fixed a bug that clipped the message at its end

function fixstring(string1)
    Dim string2,pstart,pos0,pos1,part
    string2=""
    pstart=1
    do
        part=mid(string1,pstart,76)
        pos0=instr(part,vbcrlf)
        if pos0=0 then
            pos1=instrrev(part," ")
            if pos1=0 then
                string2=string2&part&vbcrlf
                pstart=pstart+76
            else
                string2=string2&left(part,pos1)&vbcrlf
                pstart=pstart+pos1
            end if  
        else
            string2=string2&left(part,pos0)&vbcrlf
            pstart=pstart+pos0
        end if  
    loop while pstart<len(string1)
    fixstring=string2
end function

string1="Lorem ipsum dolor sit"&vbcrlf&"amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed in dignissim risus. Vestibulum ac justo sed massa posuere pellentesque non et odio. Suspendisse scelerisque sed ante in ullamcorper. Sed vel diam sed ligula commodo aliquet. Fusce aliquam eleifend arcu, vitae euismod purus pellentesque ac. In adipiscing, eros a semper semper, magna ligula volutpat dui, a vulputate nisl tellus a nisi. Donec et fringilla tellus. Praesent nibh neque, hendrerit ut fringilla eget, condimentum nec ligula. Mauris porta et velit et faucibus. Morbi aliquam risus urna, eu ultricies purus venenatis eget. Donec elementum ante dictum, euismod augue at, euismod lorem. Praesent sit amet tempus est. Nam et neque mollis, pretium ante sed, aliquet enim. abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrs Integer vestibulum lacus euismod lectus placerat, ut commodo metus tempor. Vivamus sagittis mauris id fringilla mattis. Nam convallis accumsan nulla nec eleifend. Suspendisse lobortis iaculis magna vel convallis. Ut id metus posuere, ullamcorper sapien at, sodales massa. Aenean commodo quis dolor vitae convallis. Duis sed metus non nisl commodo porttitor a sed augue. Vestibulum non risus bibendum, aliquam nulla vel, imperdiet sem. Suspendisse mattis eu lorem ac accumsan. Donec eget pulvinar libero. Nam cursus gravida gravida. Proin interdum elementum euismod. Nunc nec viverra ipsum. Nunc ultrices purus nisi, sed scelerisque elit suscipit ut. "
response.write "<b>string1:</b><br>"&string1&"<BR><br>"
response.write "<b>string2:</b><br>"&replace(fixstring(string1),vbcrlf,"<br>")
%>
```

Comment: Watch out - this function is a little broken. The remaining text on the last line is lost when you use this!

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found is to use this code:

```
ObjMail.HtmlBody="text of your message"
'*** NOTE: the following instruction has to be placed HERE, just after the HtmlBody
ObjMail.HtmlBodyPart.ContentTransferEncoding = "quoted-printable"
```

It seems to work flawlessly!

Answer (score 0):

This happens when there are over 750 characters per line. Try use vbNewLine or Chr(10) to split lines in html.

Example:

```
Set rs = conn.execute(txtsql)

html = ""
html = html & "<h1>Hi " & rs("Engineer_Name") & "</h1>" & vbNewLine
html = html & "<div class=''><table class='maintable'>" & vbNewLine
html = html &   "<thead>"
html = html &       "<tr>"
html = html &           "<th>ID</th>"
html = html &           "<th>Title</th>"
html = html &       "</tr>"
html = html &   "</thead>" & vbNewLine
html = html &   "<tbody>" & vbNewLine

Do Until rs.EOF
    html = html &       "<tr>"
    html = html &           "<td>" & rs("ID_Calendar") & "</td>"
    html = html &           "<td>" & rs("Title") & "</td>"
    html = html &       "</tr>" & vbNewLine
    rs.movenext
Loop

html = html &   "</tbody>" & vbNewLine
html = html & "</table></div>"
```