# Extra ! sign in email message body while sending mail through shell script

Tags: shell, email

I am sending emails through shell script, in which I get message body from a text file. Issue comes when my disclaimer goes long, it starts getting extra ! sign in between.

Please suggest me to remove that without shortening or giving extra lines between the disclaimer. Let me know if you need any details.

---

**Needed(say)**:

> I am sending emails through shell script, in which I get message body from a text file. Issue comes when my disclaimer goes long, it starts getting extra ! sign in between.
>   Please suggest me to remove that without shortening or giving extra lines between the disclaimer. Let me know if you need any details.

**Output in mail**:

> I am sending emails through shell script, in which I get message body from a text file. Issue comes when my disclaimer goes long, it starts getting extra ! sign in between.
>   Please suggest me to remove that without shortening or giving **e!xtra** lines between the disclaimer. Let me know if you need any details.

Here you can see that we are getting ! sign in **extra** word. Just keep the body long (sry I couldn't provide you the actual text), and you will get the ! sign.

**Code I am using** - to read from text file

```
EMAILMSG=$(cat $2)   # $2 is path of text file
```

to send email

```
(echo -e $EMAILMSG;) | mailx -s "$SUBJECT" -b "abc@abc.com" $EMAIL -r $MAILBCC
```

I think this will help you to understand the situation. Please let me know anyone need further details.

Comment: An example input and the set of commands you use would be helpful, so we can reproduce it.

Comment: Just added the details..

Comment: Why not `(cat $2;) | mailx -s "$SUBJECT" -b "abc@abc.com" $EMAIL -r $MAILBCC` ?

Comment: @PeterMmm, why `cat X | Y`? It's more efficient to do `Y < X`.

Comment: as $2 seems to be a file, hvae you tried inspecting the file separately from sending it by email? I would give a 99% probability that the '!` is in the file. Then the question is why is the program that produced file ($2) is adding `!` to its output. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter: I have checked that file, the content in file is good. I think problem occurs while sending the mail, beacuse on checking log I found that value of $EMAILMSG is coming fine.

Comment: Ok. thanks for checking. In the meantime, I think @glennjackman has found a likely solution to your problem. Good luck to all.]

Answer (score 4):

I found this: [Random exclamation mark in email body using CDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177865/random-exclamation-mark-in-email-body-using-cdo)

It seems to indicate long lines are the problem. Try this using [`fold`](http://man.cx/fold) to wrap lines:

```
fold -s "$2" | mailx -s "$SUBJECT" -b "abc@abc.com" "$EMAIL" -r "$MAILBCC"
```

Style recommendations:

1. don't use `$ALL_CAPS_VARS` ([here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/114601/4667)'s why not)
2. always quote your `"$vars"` except when you know exactly when not to.

Comment: +1 That's my guess, too. The proper solution is to wrap your message body in a suitable transfer encoding such as quoted-printable.

Comment: On using fold I lost my attachment and gets encrypted message body. For the time being I have added a new line (\n) between disclaimer. But I need a good solution for this. Exact command I am using is,    (echo -e $EMAILMSG ; uuencode "$CNAME" < "$ATTACHMENTPATH/$CNAME") | mailx -s "$SUBJECT" -b "abc@abc.com" $EMAIL -r $MAILBCC  .. where $CNAME is custom file name.